# Nested environments: is sequence important?

Tags: minipage, polyglossia, nesting

In the MWE right at the bottom, I define a new environment called `teacheronly` which wraps text inside two environments.  The first environment is a `polyglossia` language setting, and the second is a framed minipage using the package `boxedminipage2e`.  I get very different results if I switch the ordering of these environments and I want to understand why.

The way I currently understand nested environments is that the sequence of nesting is usually unimportant.  In other words, in the following pseudo-code, `environ1` can be switched with `environ2` a lot of the time.

```
\begin{environ1}
\begin {environ2}
some text
\end {environ2}
\end {environ1}
```

But in my MWE below,  if the `english` environment lies *outside* the `boxedminipage` environment, I get good results.  But if the `english` environment is lies *inside*, I get two strange effects:

1. the `english` environment 'breaks' and reverts to Arabic for no apparent reason
2. the pagination changes.

Can someone explain these to me?  I had expected the output to be identical.
The crucial text is inside the box at the end of the document.  It moves to the next page if I change the sequence of environments.

I would prefer to have `english` as the inside environment, because my real-life text (not the MWE) will want to include within the `boxedminipage` environment not just one `english` environment, but several different language environments.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.0in, bottom=1in, inner=1.6in, outer=1in, includefoot] {geometry}
\usepackage{boxedminipage2e}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{polyglossia,}
\setlength{\parskip}{4.5ex plus 0.2ex minus 0.2ex }
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.70]{Scheherazade}
\NewEnviron{teacheronly}[1]
{
\begin{english}
\begin{boxedminipage}[t][#1][t]{\linewidth}
    \BODY% Comment this to remove `...more marked tex...`
\mbox{}
\end{boxedminipage}
\end{english}
}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\section{ففف غغغ جكجج للل ددد }
اهسيجحد هايحجدس هايس دهاسيج د؛هايسج 

؛اسح

\begin{teacheronly}{1in}

\end{teacheronly}

ا؛حسد ةه؛اوسحد ؛هاسح  اهسدح ؛هاوسحد 

\begin{teacheronly}{1in}

\end{teacheronly}

الوعد  ”وَتَتَبَارَكُ فِيكَ جَمِيعُ قَبَائِلِ ٱلْأَرْضِ" -هو متحقق إزّي؟

\begin{teacheronly}{1in}

\end{teacheronly}

\section{نتوقع إيه  بعد كده تتت ثثث ظظظ}

إاسكلدجح ايسودغ يسدو غيشوغ يسدوح صسخيه؛وح ص
اةيهسوح يسهدوحص هوسدصح 

\begin{teacheronly}{1in}
Read  and write what you expect to happen next in the story.

This is another paragraph

This is another
\end{teacheronly}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Typically, order *does* matter. Consider `\begin{tabular}{cc}\begin{table}...` or `\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{figure}...` or `\begin{itemize}\begin{quotation}`... etc. Or `\begin{minipage}{<width>}\begin{center}` versus `\begin{center}\begin{minipage}{<width>}`....

Comment: I can't get the pagination to change. I can get the breaking of the left-to-right setting, but the pagination is unaffected.

Comment: `boxedminipage` is setting things into an `lrbox` so maybe it is not so surprising this runs into difficulties...? If you put the contents into a `minipage` within the `english` environment within the `boxedminipage`, then it will work e.g. `\NewEnviron{teacheronlyx}[1]
{%
  \begin{boxedminipage}[t][#1][t]{\linewidth}
 \begin{english}
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \BODY
   \end{minipage}
 \end{english}%
  \end{boxedminipage}%
}
`.

Comment: Testing this would have been easier for us without this specific Arabic font setting -- not everybody has Scheherazade font installed nor does he understand/can read Arabic scriptures ;-)

Comment: @christian-hupfer Sure, I'll use Arial next time.

Comment: @Tim: Rather don't use `xelatex` here at all -- not everybody uses it and not everybody works on Windows having Arial etc.

Comment: @cfr I agree, order does matter.  Just to clarify my question, I'm not after a how-to-fix type of solution but a "why does it do this strange thing"?

Comment: @christian-hupfer I thought xelatex might be the problem.  For newbies like me, there's very little way to determine the source of the problem.

Comment: @cfr Do you want to write a (general) answer?

Comment: @TeXnician I can't recreate the problem the OP reports. Only, now, I can get the pagination change, but not the break in LTR typesetting. Moreover, using a `minipage` no longer makes any difference. But I'm not sure what is supposed to go wrong with the pagination anyway.